# How do I print the previous and next numbers of a given input?

Tags: python

```
def printPreviousAndNext():
  take = input()
  print("The next number for the number" + take + "is" + int(take+1))
  print("The previous number for the number" + take + "is" + int(take-1))
printPreviousAndNext()
```

As you can see I want to give an input and want to print its previous and next numbers for example:

```
my input: 200
```

What I want the result to be is:

```
The next number for the number 200 is 201
The previous number for the number 200 is 199
```

But I am getting an error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
  File "python", line 3, in printPreviousAndNext
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The error message seems clear, `"a" + 1` isn't something Python lets you do. Have you researched it? Looked into the various string formatting methods?

Answer (score 1):

The error message really says it all, you are trying to concat a string and a number, what you really want is to concatenate two strings.

```py
def printPreviousAndNext():
  take = int(input())
  print(f"The next number for the number {take} is {take+1}")
  print(f"The previous number for the number {take} is {take-1}")
printPreviousAndNext()
```

Formatted with f-string even takes care of the convertions. (@Matthias)

Comment: Using an f-string makes this even nicer: `print(f'The next number for the number {take} is {take+1}')`

Comment: very true, no need to convert yourself